# How to control a movieclip that was loaded using loadclip() in AS2?

Tags: actionscript-2, movieclip

This is in AS2. I'm loading an external AS2 swf using the loadclip function.

But I don't know how to call its gotoAndPlay or stop functions. How do I reference to them?

When I trace the loaded file it says

```
_level0.mcContainer.instance42
```

The object path always varies every load like now it's instance42 sometimes it becomes instance7 or instance10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was wrong. instance42 refers to the anonymous instances inside the loaded swf. upon loading the loaded clip replaces the container movieclip, hence I can refer to the loaded swf using mcContainer.